# Suggestions for bounties

Tags: discussion, bounty

I no longer contribute to Stack Overflow any more (although I am still active on other stacks). An answer to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-%ce%98n-logn/2095472#2095472) that I posted (that should really have been a comment) was greatly expanded by other users, and is constantly being upvoted, and I have acquired a lot of reps for doing very little work.

I would like to give these reps back in the form of bounties, but since I don't follow SO any more, I have no idea what unanswered questions deserve bounties. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: all of my questions/answers deserve bounties (/s)

Comment: @KevinB I should have anticipated that. :-P

Comment: @Mick well.... that is kind of a meta 'no work done' question. While your intent is laudable, you are basically asking the community to do your research about which Q deserves a bounty. Could definitely be a reason for downvotes

Comment: @Patrice You're right, but I wasn't sure what to do. I did think about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's perfectly natural to not want something with perceived value to go to 'waste', but arbitrarily inflating the value of posts based on anything but how valuable *you* found them isn't really helping.

If you want to do something and you have a modicum of time to spend, check the site occasionally for new questions by new users that are written reasonably well, but failed to really get any traction. This could simply be because they weren't tagged very well, or perhaps the problems being described require a bit of rare knowledge.

Watch for those, and give 'em a boost if you want, you might have some fun doing it. But please, don't inflate stuff that you don't personally see much value in, even if others recommend it - that's not how the system is supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks, @Tim. That's useful. I've just checked for questions with no answers, and I'm surprised at how many of these have a lot of upvotes. I'll check in periodically and award bounties to those that pique my interest (and that I actually understand).